# Formatar data(tipo date sql) com javascript sem alterar o tipo

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-schema

Pegar um campo de data do tipo date yyyy-MM-dd (sql)
usar uma função javascript diretamente no arquivo XML para
mostrar essa data no formato dd-MM-yyyy
sem alterar o tipo, permanecendo Date.

É possível?

Comment: Eu acredito que tudo é possível, mas nem tudo é viável. O que seria esse arquivo .mdx ? você quer conectar nele via Javascript?

Comment: O arquivo é em XML. Cubo no Pentaho. XML SCHEMA  :)

Comment: Eu tenho a data no formato date que é o que preciso. Tem que esta no formato date para os filtros que serão aplicados. Então, a data esta vindo no formato americano. Acredito que usando JavaScript na hora de imprimir a data a data estará no formato date, porém com uma mascara... Preciso de uma máscara que não mude o tipo. Pois no SQL dá pra colocar a mascara, mas altera o tipo para String.